# How to generate new thread groups via beanshell in Jmeter

Tags: java, multithreading, automation, jmeter, beanshell

I have created a beanshell script in beansheill Timer where I am adding delay between requests. That delay is calculated based on a csv file where I have timestamps all requests.

Now problem I am facing is Within a thread group If one request is taking execution time more than the delay then second request can't be executed. It would have to wait until previous request has been served.

So to solve such problem, I would have to create a new thread group and execute it programmatically. Can someone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create and add a Thread Group in JMeter runtime while the script is executing

So the options are in:

1. Execute the requests programmatically using [Future Tasks](https://www.baeldung.com/java-future) and [HTTP Components](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e49) and modify metrics from script
2. Set response timeout programatically, this is where the setting lives in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (if your test assumes [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP))

   [image]

   this way the request won't last longer than the anticipated value
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so it looks like you should reconsider the scripting language in any case, [Groovy performance is much better and it offers a lot of enhancements on top of normal Java SDK](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: can you share a sample code how can I use jsr22 3 script to create new thread group?